# How to implement a routing problem with passengers

Tags: or-tools

I would like to solve routing problems with passengers. At most 4 passengers can be present in a vehicle. At each stop either passengers enter the vehicle or leave the vehicle. As I understand this can not be modeled with a demands dimension, as the cumulative variable is only allowed to increase (non-negative transits). What's the approach here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have negative transits.
You cannot have negative cumulative variables.

Comment: Ok, correction, I can have negative transits. But to model the number of passengers in a vehicle at a stop I need to reference the cumulative value, right?

Comment: I think I misundertood something here. So the cumulative value is allowed to increase and decrease as long as it remains positive? Passengers can be modeled with a demands dimension?

Comment: Exactly. This is how pdp is implemented.